# Do moose usually browse woody foilage approximately perpendicular to the long axis of the branch?

Tags: ecology, ethology

I am trying to improve my understanding of [moose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moose) browsing behavior. One basic question is whether browsing on woody vegetation can tell us anything about the orientation of the moose's head. The following are videos I have watched that feature moose browsing on woody vegetation.

- [moose eating trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxLM8a37My4)
- [Moose Eating Tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yB6wQ9B0rDM)
- [Moose Browsing in Winter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VukIyB07LQ0)
- [moosing eating tree](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zxAbgkRLDFY)
- [Alaskan moose cow and calf browse on budding tree branches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vrK3scJSEo)
- [Moose fences to protect ... trees?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsAVvKIMyP0)
- [Bull Moose browsing tree branches in Maine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjrXWpDEYuE)
- [Albino moose getting drunk on apples and fighting the local lawnmower to the death!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk9DiaH8zsk) (just at the beginning)
- [Bull Moose browsing in meadow at 11,000 feet.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUJi3P500GQ)
- [Moose Browsing in Platte River Wilderness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52SWbm2rfRY)
- [North Platte River Adventure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESn6yHcPJAI&t=39s) (at t=39s)

From these videos I have made some inferences.

- For really short trees and brush a moose is might feed on buds from above.
- Depending on the height and thickness of the central stem of a bush or tree, a moose might bite on it sideways to bend/break it into a horizontal orientation.
- For branches off the side of larger trees I see that often the moose's head comes from roughly perpendicular to the branch rather than straight-on.

Is it more generally known that moose tend to browse from the side (i.e. roughly perpendicular) to branches on (larger) woody plants rather than straight on?

Comment: Note that [this other question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108071/can-we-infer-the-orientation-of-a-mooses-head-from-the-teeth-patterns-on-tree-t) is about teeth marks on bark, whereas this question is about how moose browse on branches.